# Installation error in Magento

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

[image: CSS and js are not loaded when new magento installation was done.Please refer screenshot for logs.]

Please help me with the solution.
I am using nginx server.Conf is as follows

```
    upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server  unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myshop.com www.myshop.com;
  set $MAGE_ROOT /home/ubuntu/myshop;
  include /home/ubuntu/myshop/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Comment: What is your document root in apache? Shoud be something like: /var/www/mysite/pub.

Comment: run all command after check

Comment: I am using nginx

Comment: Mageroot is wrong, should be /home/ubuntu/myshop/pub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx config looks ok (mage root is defined in nginx.conf.sample). Check your files owner and permissions. Also try to remove some generated files: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html.

Did you set the project into development mode? Run the `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` in cli. If not set it to: `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: What was the solution in your case? I’m just curious :)